# extract ISO with winrar automatically with c# or batch

Tags: c#, batch-file, winrar

I'm trying to extract an ISO to a folder with the same name without .iso on the end.

I'm having a problem with winrar as it will not start the extract when I start up with the seach starting in the folder with the ISO.

**UPDATED with answer code**

```
private void ExtractISO(string toExtract, string folderName)
    {
        // reads the ISO
        CDReader Reader = new CDReader(File.Open(toExtract, FileMode.Open), true);
        // passes the root directory the folder name and the folder to extract
        ExtractDirectory(Reader.Root, folderName /*+ Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(toExtract)*/ + "\\", "");
        // clears reader and frees memory
        Reader.Dispose();
    }

    private void ExtractDirectory(DiscDirectoryInfo Dinfo, string RootPath, string PathinISO)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PathinISO))
        {
            PathinISO += "\\" + Dinfo.Name;
        }
        RootPath += "\\" + Dinfo.Name;
        AppendDirectory(RootPath);
        foreach (DiscDirectoryInfo dinfo in Dinfo.GetDirectories())
        {
            ExtractDirectory(dinfo, RootPath, PathinISO);
        }
        foreach (DiscFileInfo finfo in Dinfo.GetFiles())
        {
            using (Stream FileStr = finfo.OpenRead())
            {
                using (FileStream Fs = File.Create(RootPath + "\\" + finfo.Name)) // Here you can Set the BufferSize Also e.g. File.Create(RootPath + "\\" + finfo.Name, 4 * 1024)
                {
                    FileStr.CopyTo(Fs, 4 * 1024); // Buffer Size is 4 * 1024 but you can modify it in your code as per your need
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void AppendDirectory(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
        }
        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException Ex)
        {
            AppendDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
        }
        catch (PathTooLongException Ex)
        {
            AppendDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
        }
    }
```

The user selects the folder to extract (.ISO)  toExtract. I then use it in the Process.Start() in the background worker. That just seems to open the mounting software and doesn't extract the ISO to the desired folder name.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Or if anyone could give me a batch to extract the ISO instead and to call it from c# passing toExtract and the folder name that would be helpful too.

Thanks

Comment: What about using http://discutils.codeplex.com/ and thereby avoiding having to shell out to some third party executable

Comment: You should be able to create a command call and do it that way. Have a look here http://www.respower.com/page_tutorial_unrar

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737/net-library-to-unzip-zip-and-rar-files

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Would that part from extracting a file from a iso, could that be used to extract a full .iso? and how?

Comment: If you can extract a file then you can extract the entire .iso. If you want to find out how to do that then you can read the documentation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If external Class Libraries are OK!

Then use [`SevenZipSharp`](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/) or [`.NET DiscUtils`](http://discutils.codeplex.com/) to extract ISO's...

These two ClassLibraries can manage ISO and Extract them!

For `DiscUtils` you can find some codes for ISO Management [`CDReader` Class] at the Link I provided.

But For `SevenZipSharp`, Please Explore the ClassLibrary source and find the Code to Extract or Google to find it!

To get the Name of the folder just use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension((string)ISOFileName)` which will return `"ISOFile"` for an iso named `"ISOFile.iso"`. And then you can use it with your desired path.

## UPDATE

Code To Extract ISO Image with DiscUtils :

```
using DiscUtils;
using DiscUtils.Iso9660;

void ExtractISO(string ISOName, string ExtractionPath)
{
    using (FileStream ISOStream = File.Open(ISOName, FileMode.Open))
    {
        CDReader Reader = new CDReader(ISOStream, true, true);
        ExtractDirectory(Reader.Root, ExtractionPath + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ISOName) + "\\", "");
        Reader.Dispose();
    }
}
void ExtractDirectory(DiscDirectoryInfo Dinfo, string RootPath, string PathinISO)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PathinISO))
    {
        PathinISO += "\\" + Dinfo.Name;
    }
    RootPath += "\\" + Dinfo.Name;
    AppendDirectory(RootPath);
    foreach (DiscDirectoryInfo dinfo in Dinfo.GetDirectories())
    {
        ExtractDirectory(dinfo, RootPath, PathinISO);
    }
    foreach (DiscFileInfo finfo in Dinfo.GetFiles())
    {
            using (Stream FileStr = finfo.OpenRead())
            {
                using (FileStream Fs = File.Create(RootPath + "\\" + finfo.Name)) // Here you can Set the BufferSize Also e.g. File.Create(RootPath + "\\" + finfo.Name, 4 * 1024)
                {
                    FileStr.CopyTo(Fs, 4 * 1024); // Buffer Size is 4 * 1024 but you can modify it in your code as per your need
                }
            }
    }
}
static void AppendDirectory(string path)
{
    try
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }
    }
    catch (DirectoryNotFoundException Ex)
    {
        AppendDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
    }
    catch (PathTooLongException Exx)
    {
        AppendDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
    }
}
```

Use It with Like This :

```
ExtractISO(ISOFileName, Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + "\\");
```

Working! Tested By Me!

And Of Course You can always add more Optimization to the code...

This Code is Just a Basic One!

Comment: Thanks for going the extra mile! You might want to use a smaller buffer and loop rather than reading the whole file into memory to make it easier to extract larger files (e.g. like [in Jon's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/411605/243245)) and maybe re-use the same buffer between files but all looks good.

Comment: @I.am.WritZ What bugs? I haven't had any problems with the extraction. Is all you added was the true to hide verisions?

Comment: Could these comments be removed now?

Comment: @Kev I am removing most of my Comments!

Comment: @ELSheepO Sometimes the code posted before would reproduce `;1` or `;0` at the end of each `FileName`...Setting `hideVersions` as `true` will solve that Problem...[For More Info See This Thread](http://discutils.codeplex.com/discussions/281328)

Answer (score 1):

For UDF or for making Windows ISO Files after servicing(DISM) with out needs  the above accepted answer is not working for me so  i tried this working method with DiscUtils

```
using DiscUtils;
public static void ReadIsoFile(string sIsoFile, string sDestinationRootPath)
        {
            Stream streamIsoFile = null;
            try
            {
                streamIsoFile = new FileStream(sIsoFile, FileMode.Open);
                DiscUtils.FileSystemInfo[] fsia = FileSystemManager.DetectDefaultFileSystems(streamIsoFile);
                if (fsia.Length < 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No valid disc file system detected.");
            }
            else
            {
                DiscFileSystem dfs = fsia[0].Open(streamIsoFile);                    
                ReadIsoFolder(dfs, @"", sDestinationRootPath);
                return;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (streamIsoFile != null)
            {
                streamIsoFile.Close();
            }
        }
    }

public static void ReadIsoFolder(DiscFileSystem cdReader, string sIsoPath, string sDestinationRootPath)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] saFiles = cdReader.GetFiles(sIsoPath);
            foreach (string sFile in saFiles)
            {
                DiscFileInfo dfiIso = cdReader.GetFileInfo(sFile);
                string sDestinationPath = Path.Combine(sDestinationRootPath, dfiIso.DirectoryName.Substring(0, dfiIso.DirectoryName.Length - 1));
                if (!Directory.Exists(sDestinationPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(sDestinationPath);
                }
                string sDestinationFile = Path.Combine(sDestinationPath, dfiIso.Name);
                SparseStream streamIsoFile = cdReader.OpenFile(sFile, FileMode.Open);
                FileStream fsDest = new FileStream(sDestinationFile, FileMode.Create);
                byte[] baData = new byte[0x4000];
                while (true)
                {
                    int nReadCount = streamIsoFile.Read(baData, 0, baData.Length);
                    if (nReadCount < 1)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fsDest.Write(baData, 0, nReadCount);
                    }
                }
                streamIsoFile.Close();
                fsDest.Close();
            }
            string[] saDirectories = cdReader.GetDirectories(sIsoPath);
            foreach (string sDirectory in saDirectories)
            {
                ReadIsoFolder(cdReader, sDirectory, sDestinationRootPath);
            }
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

it has extracted from a application source ISOReader but modified for my requirements

total source is available at http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp_Free_CodeDownload/i/isoreader.zip

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string Desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
Process.Start("Winrar.exe", string.Format("x {0} {1}",
   Desktop + "\\test.rar",
   Desktop + "\\SomeFolder"));
```

That would extract the file `test.rar` to the folder `SomeFolder`. You can change the .rar extention to .iso, it'll work the same.

As far as I can see in your current code, there is no command given to extract a file, and no path to the file that has to be extracted. Try this example and let me know if it works =]

P.S. If you'd like to hide the extracting screen, you can set the `YourProcessInfo.WindowStyle` to `ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden`.

Comment: Hi just tried it getting the error message "no archives found" I changed round the code in the backgroundworker to what you gave me, and changed the files to what I wanted them to be. 
        
            string Desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            Process.Start("Winrar.exe", string.Format("{0} {1}",
               Desktop + txtToExtract.Text,
               Desktop + txtFolderName.Text));

Comment: Make sure you add two backslashes (`\\ `) after Desktop. Else it reads it as `C:\User\MyUser\DesktopMyIsoImage.iso` instead of `C:\User\MyUser\Desktop\\MyIsoImage.iso`

Comment: `string MyDocuments = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            Process.Start("Winrar.exe", string.Format("x {0} {1}",
               toExtract,
               MyDocuments + "\\ISO DUMP!!" + folderName));` Is what I changed it to, getting that there is no archive, toExtract is the full extention of the ISO as I have it printed to a textbox to check it and foldername is the folder i want to extract it to, same name just without the .iso on the end, which is removed.

Answer (score 0):

I hace confrunted recently with this kind of .iso extraction issue. After trying several methods, 7zip did the job for me, you just have to make sure that the latest version of 7zip is installed on your system. Maybe it will help 
    try
            {

```
            Process cmd = new Process();
            cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            cmd.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            cmd.Start();

            cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("C:");
            //Console.WriteLine(cmd.StandardOutput.Read());
            cmd.StandardInput.Flush();

            cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd C:\\\"Program Files\"\\7-Zip\\");
            //Console.WriteLine(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
            cmd.StandardInput.Flush();


            cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(string.Format("7z x -y -o{0} {1}", source, copyISOLocation.TempIsoPath));
            //Console.WriteLine(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
            cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
            cmd.StandardInput.Close();
            cmd.WaitForExit();
            Console.WriteLine(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message + "\n" + e.StackTrace);
            if (e.InnerException != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException.Message + "\n" + e.InnerException.StackTrace);
            }
        }
```